# Maximum Index of an array and it's length on a platform

Tags: c, arrays

In **C**, the index of an array of `char` can range from `0` to `2 ^ (sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BITS)`, but the count of the array's members, is that number plus 1, which can't be hold by a `size_t` variable.

For example, in **x86**, if `sizeof(size_t)` is `4`, then the index can go from `0` to `0xFFFFFFFF`, but the count of the members, if the array is full, is `0xFFFFFFFF + 1`. which can't be hold by `sizeof(size_t)`.

1) Is this correct?
2) I'm considering to limit the highest index to `0xFFFFFFFE`, is there any better solution?

I know this example is extreme, but I want to use it as a reference.

Comment: This is only true for `char` arrays, because `size_t` is also the maximum size in bytes. For any type where sizeof(T) > 1, the maximum index will be `2^sizeof(size_t)/sizeof(T)`, and adding 1 to that is still safe.

Comment: You'll run out of virtual memory long before you hit the theoretical array-size limit.

Comment: @tkausl why is that? `0xFFFFFFFF` is just 4 giga bytes, can't virtual memory be bigger than the physical one which can be more than that these days?

Comment: `2^sizeof(size_t)` should be `2^(CHAR_BITS*sizeof(size_t))`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank's for correcting the formula

Comment: @BiteBytes If `size_t` is just 4 bytes, you're on a 32-bit system, so you can't  have more than 4GB virtual memory. If you're on a 64-bit system, `size_t` will be 8 bytes.

Comment: In either case, it's safe to treat `size_t` as bigger than any array you could actually create.

Comment: Standard C functions that deal with pointers treat address zero as invalid, `NULL`. So, even when `size_t` and a char pointer can hold the exact same number of unique values  – which is the case on most architectures  –, `size_t` suffices to describe the size of any array you can work with in C. (Yes, that does leave the zero address unusable with most standard C functions, but on many OSes it's reserved anyway, for detecting NULL pointer dereferences.)

Comment: Off by 1.  Max value of an index is "2 ^ (sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BITS) - 1", or better yet `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: if you get to the stage you need to create 2^32 -1 long C string - it will be an indication that you have start learn programming from the beginning

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I'm exploring the limits. And this is one of the purposes of a science called Computer Science.

Comment: I've experienced `strings` reaching the length of `SIZE_MAX` on early 16-bit machines.  I expect similar problems when 2 to 4G objects become inexpensively common - maybe a decade from now.  The `int` being 32 bit, even on 64-bit machines contributes to this future problem.

Comment: `a science called Computer Science` but you ask elemetary math questions. The object size can be `2^(CHAR_BITS*sizeof(size_t)) -1` bytes and for the char arrat max index will be `2^(CHAR_BITS*sizeof(size_t)) -2`. Max C string length can be `2^(CHAR_BITS*sizeof(size_t)) -2` bytes + trailing zero

Comment: @PeterJ_01 first its  `SIZE_MAX - 1` and not `2^(CHAR_BITS*sizeof(size_t)) -1`, second, this not the point, my important question is how to hold the information of the size of the array.

Comment: @Bite Bytes - you explore the limits, not the implementation limits as I understand. But anyway on the most 32bit         `#define SIZE_MAX UINT_MAX` or `__SIZE_MAX__` which is equals `UINT_MAX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Objects*

The largest size of an *object* is about `SIZE_MAX`.  `sizeof object` returns the size of any *object*.  The type returned is type `size_t`.   The range of `size_t` is `[0...SIZE_MAX]`.

The size limit is effective one less as the address after the object needs to be computable.

Since an *array* is an *object*, the largest 4-byte `int` array would be

```
int big_int_array[SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int)];  // Perhaps 1 less
```

---

*Allocations*

The largest memory that be be allocated via `malloc()` is about `SIZE_MAX`.

```
char *big_array = malloc(SIZE_MAX - 1);
```

The largest memory that be be allocated via `calloc()` is about `SIZE_MAX * SIZE_MAX` bytes, yet such a large allocation attempts usually return `NULL`.

```
double *big_array = calloc(SIZE_MAX/2, sizeof *big_array);
```

Rare machines allows this, not Linux.  Most platforms will returns `NULL` if the product meets/exceeds `SIZE_MAX`.

Here, `big_array[]` can be indexed `[0...SIZE_MAX/2)`.  This usually requires the address scheme to not be the traditional universal linear model many platforms employ.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard says that the size of an object is returned with `sizeof` and its type is `size_t` and the return value is in bytes, so it could be pretty safe to say that for all sorts of ordinary objects, the absolute maximum size in bytes would be `SIZE_MAX`. One cannot allocate an object greater than `SIZE_MAX` with `malloc`, `realloc`; but the API of `calloc` could allow that.

Therefore any array has maximum of `SIZE_MAX` elements.

While a single object cannot exceed `SIZE_MAX`, the total number of bytes in all objects in a program may well exceed `SIZE_MAX`.